# Validation Library Design Pattern selection

Tags: java, design-patterns, validation

I am writing a library which is used for validating some specific objects. 
I implemented it like strategy pattern.

**What is the best pattern for implementing a validation library ?**

Some of my code is shown below.

```
     //INTERFACE
     public interface IValidator {

            public  boolean validate(Object o) throws ValidationException;

        }


    //VALIDATOR OBJECT
    public class Validator {

        private IValidator validator;

        public Validator(IValidator validator)
        {
            this.validator=validator;
        }

        public boolean validate(Object o) throws ValidationException
        {
            return this.validator.validate(o);
        }

    }

    //EMAIL VALIDATOR 
    public class EmailValidator implements IValidator{

        @Override
        public boolean validate(Object o) throws ValidationException {

    //VALIDATE E MAIL HERE

            return false;
        }

    }


//TEST RUN
Validator validator = new Validator(new EmailValidator());
validator.validate("some email");
```

Comment: I would skip the whole `Validator` class and rename the interface to `Validator`. The validator class doesn't seem to really have a purpose.

Comment: No, not. Why do you think of when  new validation classes is came  Like AddressValidator, PhoneNoValidator. It will not be flex design.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer to this question is mainly subjective so I can only give my own opinion:

I myself use the strategy pattern as well for such tasks because that is what it is meant for. You use a specific validation strategy depending on the input of the function so the strategy pattern is alright, I think.

Read the first part of the Wiki article about the strategy pattern [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Their main example is also about validation.

Comment: Really thanks for your explanation. I read it on wiki, but it was long time ago. So I have missed this detail. It's so clean now.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I would enhance your code as below:

```
//INTERFACE
public interface IValidator<T> {
       void validate(T arg) throws ValidationException;
}

//EMAIL VALIDATOR 
public class EmailValidator implements IValidator<Email email>{
    @Override
    public void validate(Email email) throws ValidationException {
        //VALIDATE E MAIL HERE, throw exception, if needed
    }
}

// Usage
EmailValidator validator = new EmailValidator();
validator.validate();     // Catch ValidatorException here to transform into business exception and appropriate error handling
```

Few points:

1. Here java Type Eraser can help implement IValidator interface with any custom implementation.
2. Validation logic is outside POJO, POJO is pure POJO :)